# Efficient Tensor Multiplication

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I have a Matrix that is a representation of a higher dimensional tensor which could in principle be N dimensional but each dimension is the same size. Lets say I want to compute the following:

[image: eqn1]

and C is stored as a matrix via

[image: eqn2]

where there is some mapping from ij to I and kl to J.

I can do this with nested for loops where each dimension of my tensor is of size 3 via

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
        I = map_ij_to_I(i,j);
        for (int k=0; k<3; k++){
            for (int l=0; l<3; l++){
                J = map_kl_to_J(k,l);
                D(I,J) = 0.;
                for (int m=0; m<3; m++){
                    for (int n=0; n<3; n++){
                        M = map_mn_to_M(m,n);
                        D(I,J) += a(i,m)*C(M,J)*b(j,n);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that's pretty messy and not very efficient. I'm using the Eigen matrix library so I suspect there is probably a much better way to do this than either a for loop or coding each entry separately. I've tried the unsupported tensor library and found it was slower than my explicit loops. Any thoughts?

As a bonus question, how would I compute something like the following efficiently?

[image: eqn3]

Comment: the best way is to use GPU programming with openCL (or CUDA)

Comment: To me this looks quite efficient. If you have the map_XY functions in the same compilation unit, they might even be inlined. This is probably the problem, when using the library. I don't have much experience with OpenMP, but given the number of loops even in the inner loop, I'm not sure if the thread management overhead will defeat the performance gain. - btw. what I wrote about the map_XY functions (inlining) also applies to the other functions, of cause.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia interesting, I will play around with this some more to see if i can't get it going a bit faster. I wasn't sure if there was a better way using striding through the matrices.

Comment: The runtime of this algorithm is O(1). It is constant time, because you always loop only 3 times. That is as efficient as one can get, in theory. Though in practice it depends on how many times you are looping. But again, you are looping only 3 times, so this is still pretty efficient and any other optimizations would be somewhat negligible (imo) because it already runs so fast. Perhaps try what @user3146542 said and use GPU programming if you want some added efficiency.

Comment: @Lansana Sounds good to me. I will give this another chance. Maybe the problems with efficiency I was observing were originating from somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah just make sure your functions aren't taking a long time. The business logic of those could add an extra layer of inefficiency.

Comment: Maybe you could also eliminate some loops. For example use 3 loops 0...9 or so but this highly depends on the functions that are not included in the example. This could help with some more efficient register usage.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia I wrote those as functions but they are actually arrays so I imagine they are about as fast as I could make them. I could re-organize my matrices so that they are looped through in a more efficient way. Right now there is a lot of jumping around because I'm following a traditional (in my field) storage pattern.

Comment: Moving out the zero initialization of D(I,J) into a separate loop might also squeeze out another nano second. Especially if the matrix is in a single memory area, this may become subject to vectorization. (If your compiler can do that). You can also move out a(i,m) calculation by one loop and use a temporary variable to save 3^5 invocations of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of work that the optimizer of your compiler will do for you under the hood. For once, loops with constant number of iterations are unrolled. That may be the reason why your code is faster than the library.

I would suggest to take a look at the assembly produced with the optimizations turned to really get a grasp on where you can optimize and how really your program looks like once compiled.

Then of course, you can think about parallel implementations either on the CPU (multiple threads) or on GPU (cuda, OpenCL, OpenAcc, etc).

As for the bonus question, if you think about writing it as two nested loops, I would suggest to rearrange the expression so that the a_km term is between the two sums. No need to perform that multiplication inside the inner sum as it doesn't depend on n. Although this will probably give only a slight performance benefit in modern CPUs...

Comment: In this application I don't think that throwing it to the GPU will save me. I'm developing a plug-in for a larger software package which already will be spreading itself out out over many processors. I have tried to make sure I don't have any functions in unnecessary loops but that is a good reminder.